# Why not double precision in Python?

Tags: python, double, precision, matrix-multiplication

I am new to Python (mostly used MATLAB and Mathematica) and I am having a problem with obtaining double-precision arithmetic with Python.

```
import numpy as np
N = 5
p= np.array([*range(N+1)])
pkp= np.kron(p,p)
pkp= pkp.reshape(N+1,N+1)
pn = np.cos((np.pi/N) * pkp)
```

Here I only get single precision for pn but if I do something like this

```
np.cos((np.pi/N) * 2)
```

I get double precision. How can I get double precision for pn or maybe even how to use np.float128?

Thank you 
Erdem

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the datatype in the `array` constructor.  Also, you don't need to unpack the `range` object to a list before passing it to `array`.

```
p = np.array(range(N+1), dtype=np.float64)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think the problem was not that since p is an integer and I should not need to convert it to float. I found that my problem was printing the number. When it is in a matrix automacially it is single precision. I solved it by np.set_printoptions(precision=16)